# Is printf in C extension module faster than writelines in python?

Tags: python, c, io

Here's my code in python:

```
for post in posts:
    ss = get_vector_local(word_list, status)
    # ss is a string
    if ss is not None:
        output_file.writelines(ss + '\n')
```

But I need to write about 1GB file.

Do I need to rewrite the output part with python-C extension module to make the output faster?

Comment: Just a brief comment... you should check for None with the `is` operator instead of equality. For the main problem, I don't know but I stay around coz it's interesting.

Comment: I guess the answer depends a lot on the system and other external factors. I suggest you try both and profile (time) the code to see which is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing Linus T., C is basically the most portable assembler and therefore beats python in pure computations hands down.

Your example on the other side deals with I/O and as long as python is able to feed the I/O buffers fast enough, there should only be a neglectable overhead compared to pure C.